# On click scroll to anchor point

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

i'm trying to get the website to scroll to the anchor point without jumping. The website is [www.nicbrwn.com/vision](http://www.nicbrwn.com/vision) .

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried the example here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/ but it still just jumps.

Comment: What code are you using to scroll ?

Comment: where is your effort? Besides you have no JS in your website

Comment: You can do it fast with [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) plugin. If you dont want the automatic scrolling you can disable it in the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

the html

```
<a href="#red">red</a>  <a href="#blue">blue</a>
<div class="section red" id="red"></div>
<div class="section blue" id="blue"></div>
```

the css

```
.section {
height:550px;
}
.red {
background-color:#F00;
}
.blue {
background-color:#036;
}
```

The JS

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

the demo
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/k2j5X/